Нужны ли запятые в этих предложениях с союзом И?

Модели интересные и цены невысокие.
Выбрать есть из чего и цены по сравнению с рынком нормальные.


Поставьте запятые:

Модели интересные, и цены невысокие.
Выбрать есть из чего, и цены по сравнению с рынком нормальные.

Это "простые" сложносочинённые предложения с равноправными, можно сказать однородными, частями, не объединёнными вопросительной или побудительной интонацией, они не входят в состав более сложной структуры. Всё по правилам, претензий ни у кого нет. (Если только вдруг контекст какой-нибудь появится.)

А если мы добавим так?
Модели интересные и цены невысокие, это настоящий Клондайк!
:)

Людмила, это уже отдельный вопрос :)
